# Error Installing cffi in new Scrapy version

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, scrapy, pip

I am getting the following error log for installing scrapy like

pip install scrapy --upgrade

on some gooogling I found a related [issue with cffi here](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/762) but the workaround mentioned there to pip install -I cffi==0.8.1 did not work either:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 05/10/14 10:40:16
Downloading/unpacking cffi==0.8.1

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
  URLs to search for versions for cffi==0.8.1:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/0.8.1
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/0.8.1
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/0.8.1: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/0.8.1 when looking for download links for cffi==0.8.1
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp26/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1-cp26-none-win32.whl#md5=43c5e5dee0623bedecddda42a3244b81 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp26/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp26-none-win32.whl#md5=b96b84d22204db3955ea89e95a26ebc6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp26/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=4ad6b4952b0aef43dc52613b3c8ce935 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=a24b8aac42b4b35009bdda89ab33173d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=748720929cf4175330f6459e13b4f45a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=39bef680d138f48f985bdb1de18ae8e1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp32/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1-cp32-none-win32.whl#md5=186fc3ae218025ec1ef506231cf55d0b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp32/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp32-none-win32.whl#md5=2e1f0db1a890bf0ba0062f182fc0214a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp32/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp32-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=999137217400787f979e85935bc8eb79 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1-cp33-none-win32.whl#md5=73259a8c2eb0869d67964d3e2dba3424 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp33-none-win32.whl#md5=b3d7b747675d86fcf43859922e1d6d93 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp33/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=9461ce831b01f36c64a84c25dbf7aaac (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp34-none-win32.whl#md5=692578ca58384689ddf6b7c399f5dd60 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp34/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl#md5=5cbbe0e74cb337a032d49c3fab35174f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.1.tar.gz#md5=d78ad460f708ddd1f550fd65fd0803e1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.2.1.tar.gz#md5=32dd211d55f6891a575cf2b5471768fd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.2.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.2.tar.gz#md5=768f1214dbaf8839d120e8dfd658aa88 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.3.tar.gz#md5=25dbc7b6182c64d08adeb6077bfa2743 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.3
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.4.1.tar.gz#md5=e2b929397207d3ec7d88786dda7da474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.4.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.4.2.tar.gz#md5=c2a35af157006e966c67d1a725e7875e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.4.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.4.tar.gz#md5=4d5cee77fcb328ece71d794dcc38b5a9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.4
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.5.tar.gz#md5=b163c11f68cad4371e8caeb91d81743f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.5
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.6.tar.gz#md5=5be33b1ab0247a984d42b27344519337 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.6
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.7.1.tar.gz#md5=dcfbb32d9a757d515801463602e4c533 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.7.2.tar.gz#md5=d329f5cb2053fd31dafc02e2c9ef0299 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.7.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.7.tar.gz#md5=2110516c65f7c9e6f324241c322178c8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.7
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1.tar.gz#md5=1a877bf113bfe90fdefedbf9e39310d2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.8.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2.tar.gz#md5=37fc88c62f40d04e8a18192433f951ec (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.8.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.tar.gz#md5=e61deb0515311bb42d5d58b9403bc923 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version: 0.8
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.1.tar.gz#md5=d78ad460f708ddd1f550fd65fd0803e1 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.1 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.2.1.tar.gz#md5=32dd211d55f6891a575cf2b5471768fd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.2.1 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.2.tar.gz#md5=768f1214dbaf8839d120e8dfd658aa88 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.2 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.3.tar.gz#md5=25dbc7b6182c64d08adeb6077bfa2743 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.3 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.4.1.tar.gz#md5=e2b929397207d3ec7d88786dda7da474 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.4.1 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.4.2.tar.gz#md5=c2a35af157006e966c67d1a725e7875e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.4.2 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.4.tar.gz#md5=4d5cee77fcb328ece71d794dcc38b5a9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.4 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.5.tar.gz#md5=b163c11f68cad4371e8caeb91d81743f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.5 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.6.tar.gz#md5=5be33b1ab0247a984d42b27344519337 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.6 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.7.1.tar.gz#md5=dcfbb32d9a757d515801463602e4c533 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.7.1 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.7.2.tar.gz#md5=d329f5cb2053fd31dafc02e2c9ef0299 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.7.2 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.7.tar.gz#md5=2110516c65f7c9e6f324241c322178c8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.7 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.2.tar.gz#md5=37fc88c62f40d04e8a18192433f951ec (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.8.2 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Ignoring link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.tar.gz#md5=e61deb0515311bb42d5d58b9403bc923 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/), version 0.8 doesn't match ==0.8.1
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1.tar.gz#md5=1a877bf113bfe90fdefedbf9e39310d2 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cffi

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\cffi.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Source in c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ali\cffi has version 0.8.1, which satisfies requirement cffi==0.8.1
Downloading/unpacking pycparser (from cffi==0.8.1)

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
  URLs to search for versions for pycparser (from cffi==0.8.1):
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.02.zip#md5=e484dcd6702770551c3d6cec1caf8dd8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.02
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.03.zip#md5=ae975c230d0f5c275ffc278c2a5c8862 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.03
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.04.zip#md5=bc652c2ee023efdd37a67aa92ca88359 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.04
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.05.zip#md5=23eb23b7f14d0361b155f25d67f82be9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.05
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.06.tar.gz#md5=b6898062ebae1ce52d355ef1039e030e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.06
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.07.tar.gz#md5=985cb5c0d7f357904e7fdff44d31e727 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.07
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.08.tar.gz#md5=923f08a99839b4fac45d2ac395e1ef7e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.08
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.09.1.tar.gz#md5=74aa075fc28b7c24a4426574d1ac91e0 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.09.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.09.tar.gz#md5=27b8018a93c11c93f8e845488a593db4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.09
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.10.tar.gz#md5=d87aed98c8a9f386aa56d365fe4d515f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/), version: 2.10
  Using version 2.10 (newest of versions: 2.10, 2.09.1, 2.09, 2.08, 2.07, 2.06, 2.05, 2.04, 2.03, 2.02)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.10.tar.gz#md5=d87aed98c8a9f386aa56d365fe4d515f (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycparser

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\pycparser.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\pycparser.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\pycparser.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pycparser.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pycparser.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pycparser.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pycparser.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  Source in c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ali\pycparser has version 2.10, which satisfies requirement pycparser (from cffi==0.8.1)
Installing collected packages: cffi, pycparser

  Found existing installation: cffi 0.8.2

    Uninstalling cffi:

      Removing file or directory c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi
      Removing file or directory c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi-0.8.2-py2.7.egg-info
      Successfully uninstalled cffi

  Running setup.py install for cffi

    Running command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\ali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ALI\\cffi\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-1ctxjo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7
    creating build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\api.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\backend_ctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\commontypes.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\cparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\ffiplatform.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\gc_weakref.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\lock.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\model.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\vengine_cpy.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\vengine_gen.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\verifier.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    copying cffi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension

    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c\libffi_msvc
    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Ic/libffi_msvc -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c\_cffi_backend.o

    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7:

    c/misc_win32.h:217: error: conflicting types for 'int8_t'

    c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/stdint.h:27: error: previous declaration of 'int8_t' was here

    c/misc_win32.h:219: error: conflicting types for 'int32_t'

    c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/stdint.h:31: error: previous declaration of 'int32_t' was here

    c/misc_win32.h:223: error: conflicting types for 'uint32_t'

    c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/stdint.h:32: error: previous declaration of 'uint32_t' was here

    c/misc_win32.h:225: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers

    c/misc_win32.h:225: warning: useless type name in empty declaration

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\ali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ALI\\cffi\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-1ctxjo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:

    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win32-2.7

creating build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\api.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\backend_ctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\commontypes.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\cparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\ffiplatform.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\gc_weakref.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\lock.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\model.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\vengine_cpy.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\vengine_gen.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\verifier.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

copying cffi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\cffi

running build_ext

building '_cffi_backend' extension

creating build\temp.win32-2.7

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c

creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c\libffi_msvc

c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Ic/libffi_msvc -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\c\_cffi_backend.o

In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:7:

c/misc_win32.h:217: error: conflicting types for 'int8_t'

c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/stdint.h:27: error: previous declaration of 'int8_t' was here

c/misc_win32.h:219: error: conflicting types for 'int32_t'

c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/stdint.h:31: error: previous declaration of 'int32_t' was here

c/misc_win32.h:223: error: conflicting types for 'uint32_t'

c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../include/stdint.h:32: error: previous declaration of 'uint32_t' was here

c/misc_win32.h:225: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers

c/misc_win32.h:225: warning: useless type name in empty declaration

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

  Rolling back uninstall of cffi

  Replacing c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi
  Replacing c:\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi-0.8.2-py2.7.egg-info
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\ali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ALI\\cffi\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-1ctxjo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ALI\cffi

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 271, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1185, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 592, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 662, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\ali\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ALI\\cffi\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-1ctxjo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ali\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ALI\cffi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp26/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.1-cp26-none-win32.whl#md5=43c5e5dee0623bedecddda42a3244b81 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/); unknown archive format: .whl` - it seems your pip is old and doesn't support wheels. Try updating pip first.